# Is there any well known concern about having abstract class with few abstract methods?

Tags: abstract-class

I've been asked to explain why it may be bad to have an abstract class that implements most of the methods (as an extreme case, only one abstract method) and has many sub-classes.

Apart from having to look at a lot of code if you change the signature of that method I couldn't think of anything else. My answer didn't seem to satisfy the questioner.

Is there any documented downside in using abstract classes this way?

UPDATE: I'm changing the question's title to make it less opinion-based.

Comment: We cannot read the questioner's mind, sorry.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, whilst it's unfortunate that the questioner didn't bother to share what they wanted to hear, that doesn't mean this question can't be answered.

Comment: @DavidArno: Considering that this is a very common, very powerful, and widely-used pattern, I would hazard a guess that the questioner has something very specific in mind, or might even be mis-informed. There's no way to know what he was thinking of without asking him.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag Ok, but this does not explains, what is wrong with David Arno´s answer.

Answer (score 4):

Some disadvantages with your approach:

1. You are coupling a large number of sub classes to that one base class.
2. You are risking running into the [fragile base class problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class) as it will be difficult to be sure that changing the base class will not break a derived class without checking all of them.
3. You are spreading the functionality over a number of classes, risking "fragmented responsibility".

You could address all of those by having a single class that takes a function/method/delegate/command object (use as appropriate for your specific language) as a parameter to the constructor. Then rather than having a large number of classes, you have one class, a collection of functions (potentially grouped together) and then use eg a factory to create objects with different functions injected as required.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing bad about this. In fact, it is a quite powerful and widely-used pattern. I have heard it called a "lever API", because by implementing just one (usually pretty simple) method, you get a large amount of functionality in return. In other words, just like with a lever, you can turn a little effort into a lot of result.

Some examples of where this is used in the wild, are:

- Ruby's `Enumerable` API: as of Ruby 2.3, `Enumerable` has 48 concrete methods (`map`, `flat_map`, `find`, `reduce`, … all of the methods you would expect from an iterable object), all of which are implemented in terms of one single abstract method: `each`. Subclasses, such as `Array`, `Hash`, `Set`, `Enumerator`, etc, only need to implement a way to iterate over themselves (i.e. `each`) and gain all the other methods for free. Pretty much anything that is even remotely collection-like inherits from `Enumerable`.
- Ruby's `Comparable` API: Subclasses only need to implement `<=>` (the combined comparison operator), and gain `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, and `between?` for free. Pretty much anything inherits from `Comparable`.
- Scala's `FunctionN` API: you only need to implement `apply`, and your object can be treated as a function. Lots of things inherit from `FunctionN`, for example `Set` inherits from `Function1[T, Boolean]` and `Array` inherits from `Function1[Int, T]`. `FunctionN` provides a number of concrete methods for composing and transforming functions, all of which rely on `apply`.
- Scala's `Traversable` API: similar to Ruby's `Enumerable`, you only need to implement `foreach`, and get almost 100 concrete methods for free. Pretty much all collections implement `Traversable`.
- The same applies to `Iterable`: implement `iterator` and get everything else for free. (In fact: `Iterable` inherits from `Traversable` and implements `foreach` in terms of `iterator` as well.)

And, of course, generally, a class with a single abstract method is isomorphic to a function type, and is often used that way. E.g.

- in Python, every object with a `__call__` method is considered a "callable" (i.e. function-like) and the `__call__` method can be called with syntax sugar like `foo()`,
- in Ruby, every object with a `call` method is considered to be function-like and the `call` method can be called with syntax sugar like `foo.()`,
- in Scala, every object with an `apply` method is considered to be function-like and the `apply` method can be called with syntax sugar like `foo()`, and
- in Java, every type with a single abstract method is considered to be a function type, and instances of that type can be constructed using lambda literal syntax

Comment: "There is nothing bad about this...". You are mistaken. Whilst it is indeed a "quite powerful and widely-used pattern", it does have it's problems, as I've listed in my answer.

Comment: Those seem to me more like general issues with inheritance of abstract classes, or in fact implementation inheritance in general. They don't seem to be specific to having a small number of abstract methods.